# I need to send the created video to ziggeo's webservice

Tags: android, ziggeo-api, ziggeo-sdk

I'm confused how can I send my video to Ziggeo's web service [https://ziggeo.com/applications]?

"I am not good at English" 
I built in CameraViewActivity And want to send the video created from CameraViewActivity to the server[https://ziggeo.com/applications]

This is code for create video to External Storage Device.
I'm need create Video sent to Ziggeo to web server.

I'm did not use `iggeo.startCameraRecorder();`

I'm using `cvCamera.startRecording(fileToSaveRecording.getPath(), maxDuration);`
is open camera create video

```
private boolean prepareRecordingFile() {
    if (fileToSaveRecording == null || !fileToSaveRecording.exists()) {
        fileToSaveRecording = new 
        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download", 
                       "tempRecord.mp4");
        try {
            fileToSaveRecording.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            return fileToSaveRecording.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    } else return true;
}
```

I would like to thank my friends.

Comment: have you checked `Ziggeo's web service` documentation about your question?

Comment: I checked, but I do not understand how to send the video created to the ziggeo service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Aunaun welcome to StackOverflow :)

My name is Bane, and I am head of support at Ziggeo. Now with that out of the way, I want to let you know that we are always happy to assist with setup :)

In your case, I would suggest using our Android SDK to record the video which would then upload it for you and can offer you additional benefits. Since you likely know this and prefer to do it yourself and then push the video up, you can still use our SDK and then under this section: https://github.com/Ziggeo/Android-Client-SDK#videos-api you can see the code example for Create Video.

This is the code:

```
  /**
  * Create a new video.
  *
  * @param argsMap  - file: Video file to be uploaded
  *                 - min_duration: Minimal duration of video
  *                 - max_duration: Maximal duration of video
  *                 - tags: Video Tags
  *                 - key: Unique (optional) name of video
  *                 - volatile: Automatically removed this video if it remains empty
  * @param callback - callback to receive action result
  */
ziggeo.videos().create(HashMap<String, String> argsMap, Callback callback);
```

So you should be fine by using the argsMap to pass the filepath to your video and then call it in.

Feel free to comment if you need any additional details, I would be happy to edit this post and make sure it is super easy to understand and use :)